# GROUP BY in a FULL OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on two tables

**PRODUCT** table
with
**PRODUCTID, PRICE**

and I am working with

**ORDERLINE** table
which has
**PRODUCTID, QUANTITY, ORDERID**

I want to join both tables so that I have

**ORDERQUANTITY**
which has
**PRODUCT.PRODUCTID, ORDERLINE.QUANTITY**
GROUPED BY
**PRODUCTID**

In other words I would like the two tables not to be like this:

```
PRODUCTID   QUANTITY
-       10          4
-       10          2
-       20          1
-       20          6
-       30          4
-       30          6
-       30          2
-       30          2
-       40          2
-       40          2
-       40          5
```

But like **this**

```
 PRODUCTID   QUANTITY
-    10          6
-    20          7
-    30          14
-    40          9
```

My current code shown below only does the first table when I try to group by productid it won't work.

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCTID, ORDERLINE.QUANTITY
FROM ORDERLINE
FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = ORDERLINE.PRODUCTID
ORDER BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID;
```

Comment: What do you mean with " it won't work"? Are you having an error, an unexpected result, ... ?

Comment: I was getting an ineligible  GROUP BY expression.

"not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: you have QUANTITY in your select statement and probably not in your GROUP BY. You should probably change it to SUB(QUANTITY). Post your whole SQL statement...

Comment: SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCTID, ORDERLINE.QUANTITY
  FROM ORDERLINE
FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = ORDERLINE.PRODUCTID
      GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
      ORDER BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID;

Comment: try this SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCTID, SUM(ORDERLINE.QUANTITY)
  FROM ORDERLINE
  FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = ORDERLINE.PRODUCTID
 GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
 ORDER BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
 ;

Comment: Thank you for your help, you were correct a sum aggregate function did it!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the join if you need only id and sum of ordered quantity :

```
select PRODUCTID, sum(QUANTITY)
from ORDERLINE
group by PRODUCTID
order by PRODUCTID;
```

Comment: I want to note that this answer is exactly what the OP is asking for.  The OP gives no evidence that an outer join is necessary, much less a `full outer join`.  It is possible that a `left join` is desired, but there is no actual hint in the question even of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple SUM aggregate function and GROUP BY query will be enough:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCTID, coalesce( SUM( ORDERLINE.QUANTITY), 0 )
FROM ORDERLINE
FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = ORDERLINE.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
ORDER BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID;
```

Comment: Coalesce function replaces NULLs with 0 - in cases when all summed values in the column are NULL then SUM function returns NULL, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about understanding your question, but I think that this sentece should give you the results you are asking for:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCTID, SUM(ORDERLINE.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
FROM ORDERLINE
FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = ORDERLINE.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
ORDER BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID;
```

Comment: A sql 'query' is not a sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the 'grammar' correction. I'll try to remember it next time I have to write in english.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCTID, SUM(ORDERLINE.QUANTITY)
FROM ORDERLINE
FULL JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = ORDERLINE.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
```

Here it is in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59fac/9)